# Binary search doesn't work for large numbers

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve problem of find square root of given number using binary search on c++ which works perfect for small numbers, but if input >= 2000000000 it doesn't work at all

code:

```
int main() {
    int n; cin >> n;
    int l = 0, r = n + 1;
    while (r - l > 1) {
        int m = (r + l) / 2;
        if (m * m <= n) {
            l = m;
        } else {
            r = m;
        }
    }
    cout << l;
    return 0;
}
```

some tests:

```
1
1

16
4
```

but

```
2000000000000000
-3456735426738
```

can't understand why...

tested the same code on python, it works good
probably it's some c++ feature which i don't know

Comment: Python has arbitrarily large integers but C++ doesn't, so `m * m` overflows. Read about the ranges of the various types in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: When the instructor taught you about the type `int`, did they not mention that the numbers it can hold have an upper and a lower bound?

Comment: Are you sure that it printed `-3456735426738` for `cout << l;`? It has way too many digits to fit into an `int`.

Comment: Instead of `m * m <= n` write `m < n/m`. And inspect better the case when `m == n/m`.

Comment: Hint: [std::binary_search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) exits.

Answer (score 1):

A number `n >= 2000000000` surely works, as long as it doesn't reach it's maximum allowed value (more on that shortly).

Because it seems you're not familiar with data types and their sizes in C and C++, I'll keep it simple.

A type of `int` is normally 4 bytes (yes, I said "normally" as there are exceptions to this rule - this is a different discussion regarding platforms and their architecture, for now, take the simple explanation that it's 4 bytes in *most* cases), meaning 32 bits. It can be **signed** or **unsigned**.

*Minor caveat: when **unsigned** is not explicitly specified, then it's considered to be **signed** by default, so `int x;` would mean that **x** can take negative values as well*

A **signed int** (signed, meaning it has both, positive and negative numbers, so apart from zero and the maximum negative number, you'd have each value "twice", once with `+` and one more time with `-`, hence the terminology of *signed*) has the following ranges: `-2147483648` to `+2147483647`.

To "increase" the maximum allowed value, you'd need an **unsigned int**. Its range is `0` to `4294967295`.

There are "bigger" types in C and C++ but I think that discussion is slightly more advanced. Short version is this: for a 64bit integer, if you're using GCC you can use `uint64_t`, if you're using MSVS you can either use `__int64`, but you can also use `uint64_t`.

For even larger values, well... it gets really complicated. Python has native support for larger numbers, that is why it works there from the get-go.

You need to check the data types available in C and C++, preferably read up on C-17 (the 2017 standard on C, which is the newest released) and C++20 (the 2020 standard for C++). The roadmap says the next standard update for both would be in 2023 (so fingers crossed :) ).

Regarding your code, however, also keep in mind what *molbdnilo* and *ALX23z* said regarding overflowing, in their comments. Even if you would cover sufficient data type ranges, there's still a risk of overflowing due to mistakes in your code:

molbdnilo: `m * m overflows`

ALX23z: `Instead of m * m <= n write m < n/m. And inspect better the case when m == n/m`

Comment: In his code, he computes `m*m` which can be as big as `n^2/4` and overflowing for large enough `n` even when a proper implementation wouldn't.

Comment: You're right, but that was already touched by you in the comments. To me it seems he didn't even know what data types there are in C/C++ and their limitations, which is usually the first thing you learn when studying a new language. So even if he **did** fix the code, if he'd ignore the data type ranges, the values would still be incorrect. That was my focus. Still, I'll add a remark regarding your comment just to make sure he covers that as well.

Comment: In comments, I didn't explain in detail why that is the issue. But you are correct too that he was unaware of something this fundamental

Comment: Well, what you did is the same "value" (so to speak) except it won't overflow thanks to division as opposed to multiplication. That's basic enough to be understood, I think. I added what you and molbdnilo said. Thanks for pointing out that I missed the overflow.